# C# moving a PictureBox over another PictureBox

Tags: c#, picturebox

I’m making a card game in c# where I create a class extended from `PictureBox` and then I create a instance of the class for every card.

I also create a class extended from `PictureBox` to hold the images for the foundations. This class holds a `.png` image with transparency.

So far so good but after setting the game table with the foundations, every time I move a card over the foundations the **PictureBox** that contains the foundation image captures a trail of the card I mover over it creating a very unpleasant visual effect.

I don’t know why the **PictureBox** of the Foundation tries to capture the image of the card moving over it.

Is there a way to solve this problem? I've tried some suggestions but with no success. Thank you for your help.

Here is a snap of code I use to create an arraylist of PictureBox. Still the same problem.

```
        PictureBox[] pb = new PictureBox[22];
        for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++) // linhas
        {
            int col = (WindowWidth - 3 * gap - 4 * larguraCarta) / 2;
            for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) // colunas
            {
                pb[cardIndex] = new PictureBox();
                pb[cardIndex].Width = larguraCarta;
                pb[cardIndex].Height = alturaCarta;
                pb[cardIndex].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                pb[cardIndex].Location = new Point(col, linha);
                pb[cardIndex].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                pb[cardIndex].BackColor = Color.White;
                pb[cardIndex].BringToFront();
```

[This is a picture of the screen so you can see what happens when I move a card over the foundation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2v05.jpg)
[image]

Comment: You should be able to redraw the canvas to fix this like `Invalidate()`

Comment: Try to include some code and if possible a screenshot of your compilation showing the problem. This should help people understand your problem more and provide relevant solutions.

Comment: The compilation is ok. There are no compilation errors. Instead of having a class for de foundations I created an arraylist of PictureBox but still the same problem.I'm putting here the code to create this arraylist and the configuration of the PictureBox

Comment: for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) // colunas
                {
                    pb[cardIndex] = new PictureBox();
                    pb[cardIndex].Width = larguraCarta;
                    pb[cardIndex].Height = alturaCarta;
                    pb[cardIndex].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                    pb[cardIndex].Location = new Point(col, linha);
                    pb[cardIndex].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                    pb[cardIndex].BackColor = Color.White;
                    pb[cardIndex].BringToFront();

Comment: @JoaquimSousa You should move all that code you posted into the question and format it. Far easier to understand.